# Powershell search progress feedback

Tags: powershell, progress, get-childitem

I am trying to search my drive for a list of files that I have the filename stored in a database for.

I have around 10 million items that I will be searching for and I can't figure out how to include progress information. Can someone help me add a percentage and possibly an estimated time to complete to this please.

```
$SqlSelectStatement = ("
SELECT filename FROM files
")

$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=DBA;trusted_connection=true;"
$SqlConnection.Open()
$SqlCommand = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
$SqlCommand.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlCommand.CommandText = $SqlSelectStatement
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCommand
$SqlCommand.Connection = $SqlConnection
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($Dataset)


ForEach ($File in $DataSet.Tables[0] | Select -exp filename) 
{
    $count = $File.count
    $list = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\temp' -Recurse | ?{$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false -and $_.Name -eq $File }

    $list.fullname | Out-File -Append 'C:\Temp\FilesFound.txt'

}
```

Comment: You are slowing down the execution of your script by using the pipeline that way.  `Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp -Recurse -File -Filter $File`

Comment: This assumes you're on PowerShell v3+. If you're not on v5.1, using the pipeline is SO much slower (v5.1 introduced 50%+ improvement on pipeline speed)

Comment: I suggest looking at some examples of `Write-Progress` which is what you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks @TheIncorrigible1 - I wasn't sure how efficient it was so hopefully this will improve things. Do you have any advice on the progress bar, I've tried with     Write-Progress but have struggled so far.